# Camel Quartz route undesired job execution at route startup

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have several routes that looks like :

```
from("quartz://" + getJobId() + "?cron=" + cronExpression + "&stateful=true")
        .routeId(getJobId())
        .autoStartup(false)
        .to(getRouteTo());
```

Those routes can be started and stopped from an administration console.
The problem I have is the following:

If a route is configured to run everyday at 17:00, currently if my route is started after 17:00,
quartz notice that it should have run at 17:00 and will try to recover that missed execution.

I don't want that to happen, what I want:

- I start my route at day1 before 17:00, the job will be triggered day1 at 17:00
- I start my route at day1 after 17:00, the job should be triggered day2 at 17:00

Is it related to the fact that I chose a statefull job ? 
I chose a stateful job to avoid concurrent execution of the same job.

Comment: I think you can configure quartz misfire, to tell Quartz what it should do in those situations.

Comment: @ClausIbsen thanks for the pointer I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Can you link to your new question, and then close this question?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I am facing the same problem and wondering if you got it working the way you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Claus's suggestion, perhaps the following would work as a parameter on the quartz job (assuming you're using a [org.quartz.SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html)):

trigger.misfireInstruction=org.quartz.SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_EXISTING_COUNT

**EDIT: Based on soilworker's comment, the above should be:**

**trigger.misfireInstruction=2**

Comment: I have tried to add trigger.misfireInstruction=2 as option and this works now.

You can't add trigger.misfireInstruction= because then camel will throw an error that it can't convert the string property to int.