# Quartz scheduler executing camel routes and autoStartup

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I'm digging into a project that uses camel routes with quartz scheduler. I'm a little unfamiliar with the environment, but trying to figure out what's happening and how everything fits together, while trying to make a change in functionality. Just not sure how.

The component is a job manager deployed to Apache Karaf. If I have schedule (quartz cron) for a job that is active, then the job runs when the cron string is matched. The schedule can be disabled (which sets toggles autoStartup flag from what I can tell). This is working as expected.

If I disable a schedule, wait for a match on the cron string, and then reenable the schedule, the job runs. I'd like to change this behaviour, configuring schedules to only execute for cron strings that are matched while the schedule is active, and not "catch up" with matches from the disabled autostartup. Is this possible?

I see a similar question was asked last October, but never answered - [Camel Quartz route undesired job execution at route startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241529/camel-quartz-route-undesired-job-execution-at-route-startup)

Answer (score 1):

On Quartz trigger there is MisfireInstruction property which can be set to `MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY` (which equals to -1)

Unfortunately, I don't known how to set this from Camel Quartz component. Adding something like `trigger.misfireInstruction=-1` or `trigger.MisfireInstruction=-1` might work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with this and see if I can get it working.